# Which rules apply for Non-Career Skill and Characteristic advances?

Tags: character-advancement, wfrp-4e

On p.48 of the Rulebook, under Non-Career Advances, it says (emphasis mine):

> Characters will inevitably want to advance Characteristics and 
>   Skills not listed in their Careers. That’s fine, if the GM feels 
>   it’s appropriate, but it costs double. *The GM might want you 
>   to find a teacher or otherwise play out this unusual education.*
>
> Non-Career Characteristic and Skill Advances cost double the 
>   amount of XP listed in the Characteristic and Skill Improvement 
>   XP Costs table.

So this is fine at GM's discretion and costs double the usual XP. But then under Endeavours there's a different set of rules (the Training Endeavour, p.199), which says:

> The Training Endeavour allows you to train in a Skill or 
>   Characteristic outside of your Career, treating it as if it were in-
>   Career. In addition to the normal XP cost, you must also pay 
>   money to the tutor. Training for Basic Skills and all Characteristics 
>   costs XP+1d10 brass pennies , where XP is the number of XP it 
>   costs to buy the Advance. Tutoring in all Advanced Skills costs 
>   double that amount. For more, see Advances, see page 43.

So, which is it? Is it GM's choice which you need to do? Or are these separate rules offering player characters two options for Non-Career Advances, one simple option at double the XP cost, one at the normal XP cost + money + an Endeavour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or are these separate rules offering player characters two options for Non-Career Advances, one simple option at double the XP cost, one at the normal XP cost + money + an Endeavour?

### Rules:

Indeed, those are two distinct possible options:

- Your GM allows access to a non-Career skill at double XP and crafts a little adventure around it. This can happen any time and any place they see fit, even during another adventure on the road.
- Your characters are in a larger city and have downtime, then they may find a teacher that allows them to treat non-Career skills as career skills.

---

### Examples:

In the iconic "Enemy Within" campaign at some point the players find a boat they liberate from enemies. It is very likely none of them has any knowledge whatsoever, no sailing, Lore (Rivers) or any navigation/astronomy so it makes sense that their good friend, the captain of the boat they are travelling with, will teach them those things before he lets them sail away in their own boat. This is an adventure reason why they are able to learn skill outside their career. They cannot just learn a random skill they like there, but only exactly what is offered by the plot.

On the other hand, in the same campaign, while in a city, every character might just go find a teacher. Assuming there would be a good chance for *every* teacher to be available in Altdorf, as long as they spend the XP, money and endeavor they can learn practically any skill or talent in their downtime there.

---

### House Rules we use:

Personally, I only allow those endeavors if you can find another *career* that teaches it or yours is not very organized (like thief or beggar). If it's only higher up in your *own* career and you follow a strict official teaching or order (Color of Magic, Cleric, Knights Order or something else) then your higher ups won't teach it "until you are ready". No skipping the lines, the hierarchy is there for a reason.

Also, if there is a teacher available for a skill that is essential to the plot, that the players did not opt in to (like that boat they liberate, that's just part of the storyline and basically forced on them) I let them buy the advances for half cost instead of double. It's unlikely they will get unbalanced over having too much sailing skill and they should be able to put their XP where they want them, not where the adventure forces them too.

Comment: Thank you for the examples, very clear!